# How to take out unneeded sets in a parameter and copy from one parameter into another

Tags: parameters, set, gams-math

I would like to remove unnecessary sets (or indices) from a parameter in GAMS

The problem is defined as the following:

I have a parameter (which I've obtained from a a GDX-file)

```
parameter
Prices_data(AreaCode,centralamerica,ItemCode,crops,ElementCode,dollars,YearCode,Year,Unit)
```

When displayed in a listing file it would look like this:

```
166.Panama    .56 .Maize     .5532.Producer Price (USD/tonne).1999.1999.USD 281
48 .Costa Rica.56 .Maize     .5532.Producer Price (USD/tonne).1999.1999.USD 217
```

However some of the data columns are useless, such as Areacode, Itemcode, elementcode, etc

I want it to be displayed as:

```
Panama.Maize.1999 281
Costa Rica.Maize.1999 217
```

Changing the parameter into this format:

```
parameter
Prices_data(centralamerica,crops,Year))
```

I asked this question in the forum.gamsworld.com and someone replied telling me to do this:

```
Prices_data(centralamerica,crops,Year) = sum((AreaCode, ItemCode, ElementCode, dollars, YearCode), Prices_data(AreaCode,centralamerica,ItemCode,crops,ElementCode,dollars,YearCode,Year,Unit));
```

However, I got an error messages saying:

```
Error 171 Domain violation for set
Error 148 Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less indices as declared
Error 149 Uncontrolled set entered as constant
```

And till now nobody has found a solution for this in the GAMS Forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your assignment you use the parameter `Prices_data` on the left and the right but with different indices. This cannot work, since just one of this matches the declaration. If you want to use the approach suggested, you need to have two different parameters (with different names) like this:

```
parameter
Prices_data(AreaCode,centralamerica,ItemCode,crops,ElementCode,dollars,YearCode,Year,Unit)
Prices_data_Clean(centralamerica,crops,Year);

Prices_data_Clean(centralamerica,crops,Year) = sum((AreaCode, ItemCode, ElementCode, dollars, YearCode), Prices_data(AreaCode,centralamerica,ItemCode,crops,ElementCode,dollars,YearCode,Year,Unit));
```